# Is there light on the surface of Venus?

Tags: light, venus

A simple question: is there light on the surface of Venus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to answer this question is from images taken from probes that landed and took pictures from the surface of the planet.  According to the [Lunar and Planetary Institute](http://www.lpi.usra.edu/), images from the Russian Venera 13 lander revealed

> The effect of sunlight filtering through the dense atmosphere appears to give the surface an orange tint.

Despite some uncertainty of the actual colour due to possible chromatic distortions because of the atmospheric composition etc. It is clear in the image from Venera 13 (below) that there is indeed light on the surface f Venus.

[image]

Image attribution (from the link above): Images courtesy of James Head (Brown University), in collaboration with USSR (now Russian) Academy of Sciences.

Observations, reported in the NASA article [NASA Scientist Confirms Light Show on Venus](http://www.nasa.gov/vision/universe/solarsystem/venus-20071128.html) reveal another potential source of light - lightning, and theorised to be

> maybe even more activity than there is here on Earth